# Can TeamCity's .NET NUnitaddin process csproj files?

Tags: .net, nunit, nant, teamcity, csproj

To cut to the chase, can the TeamCity .NET NUnitLauncher process Microsoft csproj files?

I ask this question because of the following.

I have a NANT build script. In this script I have a number of tests which use nunit-console.exe (which ships with NUnit v2.5.2).

An example of a test in my Nant build file is:

```
<target name="x.Commons.Tests" depends="xCore">
<exec program="${nunit-console.exe}" commandline="${nunit-console.args} Core\x.Commons.Tests\x.Commons.Tests.csproj" failonerror="${nunit-console.failonerror}"/>
 </target>
```

FailOnError is set to false, and the nunit-console.args is set to '/nologo'.

When I run these tests on my local machine I get test output. However when I instruct TeamCity to build my NAnt build file, and instruct it to process the test targets I get no test output to TeamCity. I can see in the log that nunit-colsole.exe is producing test result output but Im not seeing this in the TeamCity dashboard.

After reading around I found some articles indicating that extra steps are required to get this input into TeamCity. Hence I modified my test to:

```
    <target name="x.Configuration.Tests" depends="xCore">
  <mkdir dir="C:\Tools\NUnit\bin\net-2.0\addins"/>
  <copy file="${teamcity.dotnet.nunitaddin}-2.5.0.dll" todir="C:\Tools\NUnit\bin\net-2.0\addins"/>
  <copy file="${teamcity.dotnet.nunitaddin}-2.5.0.pdb" todir="C:\Tools\NUnit\bin\net-2.0\addins"/>
  <exec program="${nunit-console.exe}" commandline="${nunit-console.args} Core\x.Configuration.Tests\x.Configuration.Tests.csproj" failonerror="${nunit-console.failonerror}"/>
 </target>
```

Note that I also made sure the  tag contains an entry of  'addins'.

However, as before I can see that the tests are working as the nunit-console.exe displays its results in the log, but Im getting no output to TeamCity.

An answer to my question, or any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<copy file="${teamcity.dotnet.nunitaddin}-2.5.2.dll" todir="C:\Tools\NUnit\bin\net-2.0\addins"/>
<copy file="${teamcity.dotnet.nunitaddin}-2.5.2.pdb" todir="C:\Tools\NUnit\bin\net-2.0\addins"/>
```

TeamCity Addin for NUnit version should match NUnit version. Please check you TeamCity version supports NUnit 2.5.2 or download newer build.

Comment: Hi Eugene,

I have TeamCity v2.5.4 installed and I found that it does not have a nunitaddin for NUnit 2.5.2. This is unusual as NUnit v2.5.2 has been around for over a year! I'm downloading TeamCity 2.5.5 and hopefully it'll have nunitaddin 2.5.2.

However, after your suggestion I changed the version of NUnit I'm using to 2.5.0, and I'm happy to say that I then got test output being displayed in TeamCity!

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Nice! Seems you referred to TeamCity 4.5.x as "TeamCity v2.5.x". As far as I know, NUnit 2.5.2 was released at August 10, 2009. http://nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5.2

Comment: Eugene, you're right, NUnit 2.5.2 was released in August '09. I've been getting confused with all these versions of different products! Thanks for the help and keep up the good work at JetBrains ;)

Answer (score 1):

The way we do it is by taking advantage of TeamCity's ability to automatically pick up NUnit tests in .csproj files.

- First, you need to install the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/).
- Then, set up your .csproj files the following way:

  - Have this in right after <Project>

    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
  - Create an ItemGroup:

    <ItemGroup>
    <TestAssembly Include="path/to/binary.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
  - Create an NUnit target:

    <Target Name="NUnit">
    <NUnit Assemblies="@(TestAssembly)" />
    </Target>
- Then, in TeamCity, in the "Runner" part of project setting, choose **MSBuild** as the runner and in the **Targets** field specify both *build* and *nunit* as targets

  Targets: **build nunit**

TeamCity should pick up the unit tests automatically on the next build.

Comment: Cheers for the reply Dr. However I'm using the NAnt build runner not MSBuild so this suggestion is not applicable not my problem.

It's a frustrating problem as I was hoping that TeamCity would pick up the test output automatically.